# JUnit assert against play.mvc.Result content?

Tags: junit, playframework

How does one assert against content within the body of a Play! JSON action Result value?  I'm returning a new (or even null) JSON ObjectNode from an action and attempting to assert against it within the result from a unit test, but don't see the value (null or otherwise) in the response.wrappedResult.body.

For example, in my action, if I return a null JSON Object Node,

```
ObjectNode response = null;
return ok(response);
```

or if I return a test value,

```
ObjectNode response = Json.newObject();
response.put("testKey", "testValue");
return ok(response);
```

and then I write a test against the result,

```
@Test
public void MyTest() {
    Result result = MyController.myAction();
    // assert against null or specified values here
}
```

and I then explore the entire object graph,

```
result.wrappedResult.body
```

I don't see anything that looks like my specified results to assert against.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at *Testing your controllers* in the [Play docs on Java testing](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaFunctionalTest) for an example of how to correctly call your actions and test Result content.

```
@Test
public void callIndex() {
    Result result = callAction(
      controllers.routes.ref.Application.index("Kiki")
    );
    assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(OK);
    assertThat(contentType(result)).isEqualTo("text/html");
    assertThat(charset(result)).isEqualTo("utf-8");
    assertThat(contentAsString(result)).contains("Hello Kiki");
}
```

Play does some clever stuff when it calls actions so you need to wrap your call in `callAction`. You won't get the same result if you call the action method directly.

Comment: Where is status() method defined? As well as contentType(), charset(), and contentAsString()?

Comment: Have a go with imports from the [previous page in the docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaTest). It's probably in the `Helper`s class.